# Как составить запрос для sqlite (возможно ли такое)

Tags: sqlite

Для таблицы:

```
index  timestamp  real
1      idx1-1     0,1
2      idx2-1     0,2
3      idx3-1     0,1
4      idx4-1     0,3
1      idx1-2     0,4
2      idx2-2     0,2
4      idx4-2     0,5
3      idx3-2     0,6
1      idx1-3     0,1
3      idx3-3     0,3
4      idx4-3     0,4
2      idx2-3     0,1
```

В столбце timestamp время в миллисекундах (для удобства показал как index X - порядок для индекса).

Возможно ли из этой таблицы получить таблицу вида:

```
index   div
1       столбец real cтроки idx1-3 / столбец real cтроки  idx1-2
2       столбец real cтроки idx2-3 / столбец real cтроки  idx2-2
3       столбец real cтроки idx3-3 / столбец real cтроки  idx3-2
4       столбец real cтроки idx4-3 / столбец real cтроки  idx4-2
```

Т.е. для индекса Х последняя строчка отсортированная по timestamp делить на предпоследнюю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаем последние строки, после чего находим для каждой из них все предыдущие в группе и опять оставляем только последние.

```
select Prev."index", Last.real / Prev.real
  from Table1 Prev
  join (
    select *
      from Table1
     group by "index"
    having timestamp=max(timestamp)
  ) Last on Prev."index"=Last."index" and Prev.timestamp < Last.timestamp
 group by Prev."index"
having Prev.timestamp=max(Prev.timestamp);
```

Пример на [sqliteonline.com](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5a49e39f8d2f0g3ljbvvy7ta)

Comment: Спасибо. Это оно :-).  а если необходимо делить не последний и предпоследний, а допустим последний и пятый с конца?

Comment: @Игорь тогда последний достаем как тут, а пятое с конца значение не join к нему, а получаем прямо в списке выборки подзапросом вроде `(select real from table1 where ... order by timestamp desc limit 5,1)`

Comment: Спасибо. Пока не понятно. Но думаю дальше разберусь. :-)